# Beamer: inside beamercolorbox, enumerate does not respect sep parameter

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I have noticed that, inside beamercolorbox, the enumerate environment does not respect -- i.e., completely ignores -- the sep parameter. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{box}{fg=black,bg=gray!30}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=30pt]{box}
Some text in a beamercolorbox with parameter sep=30pt. The text is separated 30 pt from the border of the box, as expected. Now comes an enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
\item First list item. First list item. First list item. First list item. First list item.  
\item Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. 
\end{enumerate}
As can be seen, the enumeration is \emph{not} separated 30 pt from the border of the box.
\end{beamercolorbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this a bug? Or is it expected behavior? In any case, how to I get around it, i.e., have an enumeration inside a colored box that has the same separation from the border of the box as the normal text?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### New attempt

- My first attempt directly patches the list environment.
- This new attempt patches `beamercolorbox` by updating the line width used by list environments. Note that `beamercolorbox` adds the value passed to `sep` option to `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`, but the line width is not updated.

```
% put these lines in preamble
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% originally defined in beamerbasecolor.sty
\xpatchcmd\beamercolorbox
  {%
    \leftskip=\beamer@colbox@ls%
    \ifdim\beamer@colbox@sep>\z@\advance\leftskip\beamer@colbox@sep\fi%
    \rightskip=\beamer@colbox@rs%
    \ifdim\beamer@colbox@sep>\z@\advance\rightskip\beamer@colbox@sep\fi
  }
  {%
    \leftskip=\beamer@colbox@ls%
    \ifdim\beamer@colbox@sep>\z@
      \advance\leftskip\beamer@colbox@sep
      \advance\linewidth-\beamer@colbox@sep       % added
      \advance\@totalleftmargin\beamer@colbox@sep % added
    \fi%
    \rightskip=\beamer@colbox@rs%
    \ifdim\beamer@colbox@sep>\z@
      \advance\rightskip\beamer@colbox@sep
      \advance\linewidth-\beamer@colbox@sep       % added
    \fi
  }
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

Variant for `beamer` v3.36, which is used by OP

```
% put these lines in preamble
\usepackage{xpatch}

% originally defined in beamerbasecolor.sty, beamer v3.36
% see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/v3.36/base/beamerbasecolor.sty
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\beamercolorbox
  {%
    \leftskip=\beamer@colbox@ls%
    \advance\leftskip by\beamer@colbox@sep%
    \rightskip=\beamer@colbox@rs%
    \advance\rightskip by\beamer@colbox@sep
  }
  {%
    \leftskip=\beamer@colbox@ls%
    \ifdim\beamer@colbox@sep>\z@
      \advance\leftskip\beamer@colbox@sep
      \advance\linewidth-\beamer@colbox@sep       % added
      \advance\@totalleftmargin\beamer@colbox@sep % added
    \fi%
    \rightskip=\beamer@colbox@rs%
    \ifdim\beamer@colbox@sep>\z@
      \advance\rightskip\beamer@colbox@sep
      \advance\linewidth-\beamer@colbox@sep       % added
    \fi
  }
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

#### First attempt

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{box}{fg=black,bg=gray!30}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@enum@
  {\usecounter\@enumctr}
  {%
    \usecounter\@enumctr
    % patch into the second argument of \list
    % here \beamer@colbox@sep stores the value passed to option sep
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\beamer@colbox@sep}%
    \addtolength{\rightmargin}{\beamer@colbox@sep}%
  }
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=30pt]{box}
    Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First list item. First list item. First list item. First list item. First list item.  
      \item Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. 
    \end{enumerate}
    As can be seen, the enumeration is \emph{not} separated 30 pt from the border of the box.
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update to first attempt

This further example contains the similar patches for `itemize` and `description` environments as well.

- Because of how `\itemized` is defined, we need `\xpatchcmd` from `xpatch` package to do the patching. Hence I replaced all `\patchcmd` by `\xpatchcmd`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{box}{fg=black,bg=gray!30}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% patch enumerate
\xpatchcmd\beamer@enum@
  {\usecounter\@enumctr}
  {%
    \usecounter\@enumctr
    % patch into the second argument of \list
    % here \beamer@colbox@sep stores the value passed to option sep
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\beamer@colbox@sep}%
    \addtolength{\rightmargin}{\beamer@colbox@sep}%
  }
  {}{\fail}

% patch itemize
\xpatchcmd\itemize
  {\def\makelabel}
  {%
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\beamer@colbox@sep}%
    \addtolength{\rightmargin}{\beamer@colbox@sep}%
    \def\makelabel
  }
  {}{\fail}

% patch description
\xpatchcmd\@@description
  {\let\makelabel\beamer@descriptionitem}
  {%
    \let\makelabel\beamer@descriptionitem
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\beamer@colbox@sep}%
    \addtolength{\rightmargin}{\beamer@colbox@sep}%
  }
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=30pt]{box}
    Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First list item. First list item. First list item. First list item. First list item.  
      \item Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. 
    \end{enumerate}
    As can be seen, the enumeration is now separated 30pt from the border of the box.
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=30pt]{box}
    Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \begin{itemize}
      \item First list item. First list item. First list item. First list item. First list item.  
      \item Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. Second list item. 
    \end{itemize}
    As can be seen, the itemize is now separated 30pt from the border of the box.
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=30pt]{box}
    Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \begin{description}[longest text]
      \item[text] First list item. First list item. First list item.
      \item[longest text] Second list item. Second list item. Second list item.
      \item[more text] Another list item
    \end{description}
    As can be seen, the description is now separated 30pt from the border of the box.
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your code, but received a series of "Undefined control sequence" errors. The first error reads "! Undefined control sequence. l.5 \patchcmd \beamer@enum@". Is there a typo in the code?

Comment: @Wolfhart `\patchcmd` is from `etoolbox` package. But `etoolbox` is already loaded by `beamer`. What version of `beamer` are you using?

Comment: The beginning of the log file reads "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)", and a little later in the log file I find the line "Document Class: beamer 2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations". Does that answer the question about the version of beamer?

Comment: @Wolfhart Yes. You are using TeX Live 2015 and the latest is TeX Live 2020. So manually loading `etoolbox` maybe required.

Comment: With `\usepackage{etoolbox}` added to your code, the patch now works on my system. Thank you! I have two more questions: 1) How does the code have to be modified in order to achieve the same for `itemize` (since `itemize` presents the same problem)? 2) Is the behavior of `enumerate` and `itemize` inside `beamercolorbox` a bug or, for some reason, expected behavior?

Comment: @Wolfhart Response to question 1: You can redefine the `\itemize` based on the its definition in [`beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty), and insert `\addtolength ...` staff in the second argument of `\list` used inside `\itemize`.

Comment: @Wolfhart Response to question 2: It can be seen as a bug. I have just opened two issues to report this to and open further discussions on beamer, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/605 and https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/606.

Comment: Concerning your answer to my first question: I am afraid that the answer is too complicated for me. What I meant to ask is: How do I need to modify the code you gave so that it works for `itemize`?

Comment: @Wolfhart I've updated my answer, the newly added example contains similar patches for both `itemize` and `description`.

Comment: @Wolfhart I've added a new attempt (to the top of my lengthy answer), which should work for every type of list environment.

Comment: The penultimate line of the new solution throws an error on my system: "! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \fail l.49 {}{\fail}". Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @Wolfhart Ah this implies that my new solution relies on something that is true in latest beamer v3.58, but is false in your local beamer v3.36. I have added a variant for `beamer` v3.36 to my answer, section "New attempt". Hope that helps.

Comment: Now it works, thank you! One last question: Is the solution for v.3.36 upward compatible? Or do I need to switch the code after upgrading to v.3.58 (or later)?

Comment: @Wolfhart No, it is not upward compatible. What `\xpatchcmd\cmd{<find>}{<replace>}{<true>}{<false>}` does is something similar  to find-and-replace. If it cannot find the exact occurrence of `<match>` in definition of `\cmd`, then the code `<false>` is used, which in my solution is `\fail`, a representative of undefined commands. Hence you need to switch the code after upgrading to v.3.58, and the solution will need upgrade if in future release `\beamercolorbox` does not contain the exact `<match>`.